# Find the derivative of $y=(2x-1)(2x+1)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Find the derivative of $y=(2x-1)(2x+1)$.

The result I got is 8x. However, my textbook answer is $4/(2x+1)^2$. I wonder what I did wrong?

I am using a different form of finding the derivatives and would prefer this way. Here are my steps: [image]

Comment: What is the textbook?  What chapter/section of the text contained this is your homework problem?  What is the author and edition of the text?  Please add this context, and please transcribe the problem *exactly as you see it appears in the text.*

Answer (score 4):

The textbook's answer is the derivative of $$y = \frac{2x-1}{2x+1}.$$  Your result is the derivative of $$y = (2x-1)(2x+1).$$  Which one is correct depends on the intention of the problem's author, i.e., whether they intended to write a division symbol or not.

Comment: Wow! I can't believe I did not see such a simple mistake! Thank you